# Sum up values received from webform?

Tags: python, list

Below is a print out of what python receives from a web form using cherrypy, I would like to add up all the values of "asset_cost_**x**"  where **x** is a dynamic number, provided that the corresponding value of "asset_allocation_capex_**x**" equals 'on'.

How could this be done as neat as possible?

I am currently trying the following code, however this code is just an indication

Code:

```
# I would like to get python to determone the total number so that can set 
# the (1,19) automatically
for x in range(1,19):
    try:
        i1 = "asset_cost_" + str(x)
        i2 = "asset_allocation_capex_" + str(x)
        i3 = "asset_allocation_opex_" + str(x)
        #kwarg1 = kwargs[i1]
        #kwarg2 = kwargs[i2]
        kwarg3 = kwargs[i3]
        kwarg3i = kwargs.get(i3)
        #if kwarg2 == 'on':
        #   print "Capex"
        if kwarg3i:
            if kwarg3 == 'on':
                print "Opex"
        #print kwarg1
    except:
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
```

webform printout:

`{'asset_description_9': u'Operations and Maintenance Manuals /
As-Installed Drawings', 'asset_description_8': u'12 Months Defects
Liability and Maintenance', 'checkbox-create_f06': u'off', 'old_asset_
d_1': u'', 'WO': u'1', 'asset_description_5': u'Level 4 Works',
'asset_description_4': u'Level 8 Works', 'asset_description_7': u'Pre
and Post Works Building 2 Smoke Management System Testing (incl re
porting and fire matrix updating)', 'asset_description_6': u'NSW Long
Service Levy', 'project_manager': u'contractors', 'asset_desc_8':
u'Structural', 'new_asset_s_1': u'', 'pc_date': u'2017-07-30', '
asset_desc_1': u'Structural', 'F06_yes_33': u'on', 'F06_yes_34':
u'on', 'asset_desc_4': u'Structural', 'asset_desc_7': u'Project',
'asset_desc_6': u'Service', 'discipline': u'BW', 'new_asset_w_1': u''
, 'new_asset_mo_1': u'', 'new_asset_ams_1': u'',
'outstanding_notaffecting_d_1': u'', 'F06_yes_22': u'on',
'asset_description_1': u'Level 9 Works', 'drawing-n-1': u'',
'drawing-s-1': u'', 'F06_yes_8':  u'on', 'F06_yes_9': u'on',
'F06_yes_4': u'on', 'F06_yes_5': u'on', 'new_asset_ma_1': u'',
'F06_yes_7': u'on', 'F06_yes_1': u'on', 'F06_yes_2': u'on',
'F06_yes_3': u'on', 'old_asset_ma_1': u'', 'const ruction_manager':
u'Dane Wilson', 'F06_no_48': u'on', 'outstanding_affecting_r_1': u'',
'new_asset_d_1': u'', 'old_asset_mo_1': u'', 'F06_yes_25': u'on',
'F06_yes_24': u'on', 'F06_yes_23': u'on', 'old
_asset_s_1': u'', 'F06_yes_21': u'on', 'asset_desc_9': u'Handover', 'outstanding_affecting_date_1': u'', 'F06_yes_39': u'on', 'd_c':
u'on', 'F06-c-48': u'', 'F06-c-45': u'', 'F06-c-44': u'', 'F06-c-47 ':
u'', 'contractor_list': u'contractors', 'F06-c-41': u'', 'F06-c-40':
u'', 'F06-c-43': u'', 'F06-c-42': u'', 'F06_yes_30': u'on',
'F06-c-22': u'', 'F06-c-21': u'', 'F06-c-20': u'', 'F06-c-34': u'',
'outstanding_notaffecting_date_1': u'', 'asset_desc_5': u'Structural',
'F06_na_6': u'on', 'F06_yes_35': u'on', 'asset_cost_19': u'10500.0',
'asset_cost_18': u'104773.76', 'F06_yes_36': u'on', 'asset_c ost_11':
u'34100.64', 'asset_cost_10': u'34100.64', 'asset_cost_13':
u'10080.0', 'asset_cost_12': u'34100.64', 'asset_cost_15':
u'34100.64', 'asset_cost_14': u'34100.64', 'asset_cost_17':
u'83279.83',  'asset_cost_16': u'34100.64',
'outstanding_notaffecting_r_1': u'', 'project_description':
u'Haymarket - Divestment of Carpark', 'F06_yes_42': u'on', 'F06-c-38':
u'', 'F06-c-39': u'', 'F06_na_17': u'o n', 'F06-c-30': u'',
'F06-c-31': u'', 'F06-c-32': u'', 'F06-c-33': u'', 'F06_na_19': u'on',
'F06_na_18': u'on', 'F06-c-36': u'', 'foxtrot': u'off', 'planner': u'
Ken Wenham', 'F06_yes_41': u'on', 'F06
_yes_40': u'on', 'F06_yes_43': u'on', 'checkbox-rpc-status': u'off', 'F06_yes_45': u'on', 'F06_yes_44': u'on', 'F06_yes_47': u'on',
'F06_yes_46': u'on', 'outstanding_affecting_d_1': u'', 'asset_alloca
tion_capex_18': u'on', 'asset_allocation_capex_19': u'on',
'new_asset_v_1': u'', 'asset_allocation_capex_14': u'on',
'asset_allocation_capex_15': u'on', 'asset_allocation_capex_16':
u'on', 'asset_allo cation_capex_17': u'on',
'asset_allocation_capex_10': u'on', 'asset_allocation_capex_11':
u'on', 'asset_allocation_capex_12': u'on',
'asset_allocation_capex_13': u'on', 'asset_desc_11': u'Structural',
'asset_desc_10': u'Structural', 'asset_desc_13': u'Structural',
'asset_desc_12': u'Structural', 'asset_desc_15': u'Structural',
'asset_desc_14': u'Structural', 'asset_desc_17': u'Structural',
'asset_ desc_16': u'Structural', 'asset_desc_19': u'Structural',
'asset_desc_18': u'Structural', 'F06-c-29': u'', 'F06-c-28': u'',
'asset_allocation_capex_8': u'on', 'asset_allocation_capex_9': u'on',
'F06-c- 23': u'', 'asset_allocation_capex_7': u'on',
'asset_allocation_capex_4': u'on', 'asset_allocation_capex_5': u'on',
'F06-c-27': u'', 'F06-c-26': u'', 'F06-c-25': u'', 'F06-c-24': u'',
'asset_cost_1': u '34100.64', 'asset_cost_5': u'34100.64',
'asset_cost_4': u'34100.64', 'asset_cost_7': u'6089.44',
'asset_cost_6': u'2070.0', 'asset_cost_9': u'12096.0', 'asset_cost_8':
u'13661.76', 'F06-c-35': u'', ' asset_description_15': u'Level 11
Works', 'asset_description_14': u'Level 7 Works',
'asset_description_17': u'Protection Hoarding and Scaffolding',
'asset_description_16': u'Level 3 Works', 'asset_des cription_11':
u'Level 2 Works', 'asset_description_10': u'Level 6 Works',
'asset_description_13': u'Pre and Post Works Smoke Exhaust Air
Measurement Testing', 'asset_description_12': u'Level 5 Works',
'F06_yes_37': u'on', 'scope': u'klhjk', 'contract_manager': u' Joel
Dixon', 'F06-c-37': u'', 'asset_description_19': u'PC Sums Available
for Project', 'asset_description_18': u'Level 1 / Gnd / Baseme nt
Works', 'address_ID': u'44196', 'Project_Description': u' Divestment
of Carpark', 'new_asset_l_1': u'', 'F06_na_32': u'on', 'F06_na_31':
u'on', 'outstanding_affecting_n_1': u'1', 'asset_number_6': u'
11230101 ', 'date_form_completed': u'', 'F06-c-18': u'', 'F06-c-19':
u'', 'F06-c-16': u'', 'F06-c-17': u'', 'F06-c-14': u'', 'F06-c-15':
u'', 'WAMS_conf_folder': u'off', 'F06-c-13': u'', 'F06-c-10' : u'',
'F06-c-11': u'', 'outstanding_notaffecting_n_1': u'1', 'F06_yes_38':
u'on', 'asset_allocation_capex_1': u'on', 'asset_number_9': u'
11230101 ', 'asset_number_8': u' 11230101 ', 'F06_na_28': u'o n',
'F06_na_29': u'on', 'F06_na_26': u'on', 'F06_na_27': u'on',
'F06_na_20': u'on', 'site': u'Haymarket ', 'asset_number_5': u'
11230101 ', 'asset_number_4': u' 11230101 ', 'F06_yes_11': u'on',
'F06-c
-4': u'', 'F06-c-5': u'', 'F06-c-6': u'', 'old_asset_a_1': u'', 'F06_yes_12': u'on', 'F06-c-1': u'', 'F06-c-2': u'', 'F06-c-3': u'',
'asset_number_7': u' 11230101 ', 'F06-c-8': u'', 'F06-c-9': u'', 'a
sset_number_13': u' 11230101 ', 'asset_number_12': u' 11230101 ',
'asset_number_11': u' 11230101 ', 'asset_number_10': u' 11230101 ',
'asset_number_17': u' 11230101 ', 'asset_number_16': u' 11230101 ' ,
'asset_number_15': u' 11230101 ', 'asset_number_14': u' 11230101 ',
'asset_number_19': u' 11230101 ', 'asset_number_18': u' 11230101 ',
'asset_allocation_opex_6': u'on', 'F06_yes_16': u'on', 'drawin g-d-1':
u'', 'F06-c-12': u'', 'asset_number_1': u' 11230101 ', 'F06_yes_14':
u'on', 'F06-c-7': u'', 'F06_yes_15': u'on', 'F06_yes_13': u'on',
'new_asset_c_1': u'', 'F06_yes_10': u'on', 'PM_contact': u '0404 828
433', 'drawing-i-1': u'', 'sp': u'30060686', 'old_asset_l_1': u'',
'checkbox-create_handover': u'off', 'F06-c-46': u''}`

Comment: Suggestion: That output looks like JSON format, so you could convert it into a Python dictionary using `json.loads(output)`, and then process the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no way of knowing the total number of `asset_cost_x` items, you could do something like the following to look through the entire dictionary:

```
asset_cost_keys = [key for key in kwargs if key.startswith("asset_cost_")]

sum = 0
for asset_cost_key in asset_cost_keys:
    i = asset_cost_key[11:] # 11 = len("asset_cost_")
    capex = kwargs.get("asset_allocation_capex_{}".format(i))
    cost = kwargs.get(asset_cost_key)

    if capex is not None and cost is not None and capex == "on":
        sum += float(cost))
```

So first we make a list called `asset_cost_keys`, which contains all keys in `kwargs` that look like `asset_cost_x`.  Note that this looks through `kwargs` in its entirety, so if this data is likely to be huge, you may want to look for another way of enumerating all cost items.

Then, for each one, we look for a corresponding `asset_allocation_capex_x`.  If the value of that is defined, and equal to "on", and the value of the cost is defined, we add the cost to a running total.

Note I haven't run this so there may be typos, but hopefully this should get you what you need.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 670, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\encoding.py", line 217, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpdispatch.py", line 60, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "example.py", line 1941, in RPC_submit
    capex = kwargs["asset_allocation_capex_{}".format(i)]
KeyError: 'asset_allocation_capex_6'

Comment: in this case asset_allocation_capex_6 does not exist

Comment: i figured thst my webform will only send the asset_allocation_capex_{} if it is selected on the form, if it is not then the asset_allocation_opex_{} is then on. how can you modify the answer to suit please

Comment: this is a print out of asset_cost_key from your code: ['asset_cost_19', 'asset_cost_18', 'asset_cost_11', 'asset_cost_10', 'asset_cost_13'
', 'asset_cost_4', 'asset_cost_7', 'asset_cost_6', 'asset_cost_9', 'asset_cost_8']

Comment: Be sure to use `kwargs.get()` rather than `kwargs[]`.  Calling get will return `None` if the key doesn't exist, but accessing it as an array will return a `KeyError` as you're seeing